# webservice as datasource in vs 2008 crystal report

Tags: web-services, crystal-reports

How to use webservice as a data source in VS2008 crystal report?

Answer (score 0):

Crystal reports can take xml as its data by setting the database drivers to ADO and the database to the location of your xml producing webservice (it takes a URL) - its as simple as that!

My original route was more convoluted that I thought; when you create the report there is an option in  the "Database Expert"  called "XML and Web Services" which gives you  an option to use an HTTP(S) data source - that should be your webservice URL. The report will then, as if by programming, automatically get data from that service.

Comment: if you want to set the data source programatically you can do that too but I would have to look up the code so let me know and I will try to get back to you by Monday.