# Can't hook Crystal for VS2010 to a Web Service data source

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm working on a Crystal Report (unfortunately) and I need to add an image that will be dynamically loaded from a SQL DB via a WCF XML Web Service. Apparently there is a option for this in VS2008 (see [webservice as datasource in vs 2008 crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429563/webservice-as-datasource-in-vs-2008-crystal-report)), but I can't see this option in VS2010.

Has this functionality been removed? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I've found an answer. It seems that you need to use the actual Crystal Reports app to do this rather than Crystal inside VS2010. (see http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1894389). I'm installing Crystal 2008 now so hopefully it will work...

Update: it worked!